# Cannot boot Windows 7 after install Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

Of course, I know my question is very similar, but I tried some ways and it didn't work.
Here is my problem: I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on Windows 7 Ultimate.

When at choosing partition for Ubuntu, I create 3 partitions for EFI(100MB), Ubuntu(65GB) and Swap(7GB). All of them are at the last of disk sectors(I resize the last part for Ubuntu when on Windows), it's also strange Ubuntu didn't recognize Windows partitions when install(whole disk displayed at free space).

Then I installed Ubuntu, everything went fine. After finished my laptop auto booted to Legacy BIOS, however it displayed a message

> This product is covered by one or more of the following patents:
>   US5,307,459, US5,434,872, UD5,732,094, US6, 570, 884, US6,115,776 and
>   US6,327,625.
>
> Realtek PCI eFFFamily Controller Series
>
> PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
>
> PXE-MOF: Existing PXE ROM. No boot device found.

But I can boot to Ubuntu by choosing ELFI mode(sorry I don't remember exactly it's name). Then I tried Boot-Repair to fix it, but it also didn't work, still got above error and I got this result:

[Boot-Repair message](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9355838/)

It's clearly tell that I have Windows installed on my laptop, but It doesn't boot.
Please tell me how can I fix this, I have to work both on Windows and Ubuntu. 
Would appreciate and thank forward for your help.

Comment: You only show a Windows boot loader in the MBR. There are no Windows NTFS partitions. I do hope you made good backups of Windows & all your data. Many Windows 7 systems installed in BIOS boot mode have hardware that is UEFI capable. So how you choose to boot & installs Ubuntu will determine if you are totally overwriting the entire hard drive or not. And if Window was in BIOS boot mode with MBR partitioning and you converted to gpt partitioning with Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode, you erased entire drive.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't accidentally format the Windows 7 partition? Cause If Ubuntu, during the installation, didn't recognize the Windows 7 partition, so it doesn't exist.

> => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

Above partition could refer to **System Reserved** by windows and it is 100 MB parition.

So access to your Ubuntu, open **GParted** application:

- if you see one partition for **windows 7** so you need to reinstall it.
- if you see two partitions and you can see the folders of
  your **windows 7** (Windows/Program files/Document and Settings ...
  etc), so you need to do [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)